# RestKit 0.22 : how to map only firstObject of an array?

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, nsmanagedobject, restkit-0.20

I am receiving more data than needed: I only want to map first object of an array of objects.
Using RestKit 0.22, how to map the following Json:

```
{ "name": "foobar",
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"] }
```

With the following model:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstTag;
```

To map `name`, I have this code:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MyObjectModel" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"name"}];
```

To map firstObject of `tags` to `firstTag`, I do not know how to proceed. Note: `MyObjectModel` is an `NSManagedObject`, so `firstTag` is `@dynamic`.

Comment: What versions of iOS do you need to support?

Comment: @Wain I need to support iOS 5.1

Comment: Ok, then I think the answer below is suitable and we can't experiment with iOS7 related API ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tried and tested approach is to create a method on the managed object which takes the full array. That method extracts the first item and saves it to the actual `NSString` property. Then your mapping is as standard as all of the data types match.

Comment: I had to create two methods in the end. `-(void)setTags:(NSArray *)tags { self.firstTag = [tags firstObject]; }` and 
`-(NSArray *)tags { id firstTag = self.firstTag; return firstTag ? @[firstTag] : nil; }` then I was able to map `"tags"` with `"tags"` using RestKit.